# Setting different resources for multiple Jupyter Notebook pods

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I recently hosted Jupyterhub in our K8s cluster. We set memory limits to 1GB so now all Jupyter notebook are with this configuration. But we have notebooks which are resource(memory and cpu) intensive and some notebooks are not resource intensive

So , is there anyway to assign different resource for multiple jupyter pods ?

I am  using  helm chart to deploy jupyterhub  https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jupyterhub/installation.html

Answer (score 2):

We use [profiles](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jupyterhub/customizing/user-environment.html#using-multiple-profiles-to-let-users-select-their-environment) to allow users to select from pods of different sizes. The pods are all deployed on large nodes, but users can select whether they get a half- or full-node pod.

As an example, we build off the daskhub configuration (full spec [here](https://github.com/RhodiumGroup/daskhub-rhg-config/blob/main/daskhub-rhg/values.yaml)):

```yaml
daskhub:
  jupyterhub:
    singleuser:
      image:
      cpu:
        limit: 3.5
        guarantee: 3.5
      memory:
        limit: 22.5G
        guarantee: 22.5G
      profileList:
        - display_name: "default"
          description: "Default notebook size"
          default: true
        - display_name: "large"
          description: "Larger notebook allowance"
          kubespawner_override:
            cpu_limit: 7.0
            cpu_guarantee: 7.0
            mem_limit: 45G
            mem_guarantee: 45G
```

These are both spawned on 8CPU / 52GB nodes, but two of the smaller pods will go on the same node (assuming 2 users selecting "default").

Comment: `singleuser.profileList` option looks promising, will test it out  :)

Comment: This solution worked to me , thanks a lot 

Comment: Looks like an interesting solution. Can you point out where is the configuration the makes sure the nodes are large nodes? Is this done to allow for a small request but high limit? meaning that the pod has "room to grow" inside the large node? @michael-delgado

Answer (score 0):

There is no other option if your PODs are managed by **Deployment** or **Stateful set**.

Either create the Different different **deployments** for multiple Jupiter notebooks having different configurations or deploy each notebook as a different **POD** with resource requirements.

i would suggest using the **VPA** which will auto-scale your deployment or stateful set and adjust the resource requirement as per need.

Check more about the VPA : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/verticalpodautoscaler